# ReferenceError: nome is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a function retrieve a callback. First the error was that callback parameter was not a function, than I tried to fix my syntax its saying that a parameter is not defined.

controller: (ERROR AT LINE 10):

```
//Tried to declare like "function registraU(nome, ... ())
    const registraUsuario = (nome, email, password, (e, usuarioCriado) => {
        UsuarioModel.findOne({ email: email }, (e, match) => {
          if (e) { return callback(e); }

          if (match !== null) {  
              return callback(null, null);
            } else {
                var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
                password = hash;
                novoUsuario = {
                    nome: nome,
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }

                var temp = new UsuarioModel(novoUsuario);

                temp.save(function(e, usuarioCriado){
                    if(e){console.log(e)};

                    return callback(null, usuarioCriado);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is the code that is calling it:

```
passport.use('local-registro', new LocalStrategy({
     nomeField: 'nome',
     emailField: 'email',
     passwordField: 'password',
     passReqToCallback : true 
   },
     (req, nome, email, password, done) => {

      UsuarioController.registraUsuario(nome, email, password, (e, callback) => {
        if(e) {return done(e); }

        if(!novoUsuario){
          return done(null, false, req.flash({"erroRegistro": "Email já cadastrado"}));
        } else {
          return done(null, novoUsuario);
        }
      });
     }
  ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring as a kind of es6 arrow function but you forgot to add the function body...

```
const registraUsuario = (nome, email, password, (e, usuarioCriado) => {...});
```

But where is the rest of you function body ??

```
const registraUsuario = (nome, email, password, (e, usuarioCriado) => {...}) => {
   // your function body
}
```

That's why you code is broken... It's not interpreted as a function declaration.